# Amazon S3 unwanted log files

Tags: logging, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Since one week, I am using a bucket in S3. I don't know why but it's getting rapidly cluttered with log files at a rate of about 1 at each 5 minutes, and the names include the time of day and some kind of hash similar to this: `2011-07-18-13-43-33-947CE3755ED3D9F5`

As far as I know, I am not asking Amazon to log anything. I have a EC2 Ubuntu machine running and a RDS MySql database along with that S3 bucket. Logging is not enabled on the bucket itself.

Where could these files come from?

Thank you very much for any insight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created other buckets and no logging occurs in them... I then have deleted the problematic bucket and now the logging problem seems to be solved...

Thanks to Cloudberryman and Geoff for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have logging enabled on another bucket?

Generally bucket logs are not saved in the same bucket but rather in another bucket that you specify. Those log files are in the format `prefix` `date` `hash`. It looks like you don't have the `prefix` set.

Comment: No other bucket... I still can't figure out where these log files are coming from. Thanks for trying to help though. :)